# What version of the gitlab-runner herm chart matches with GitLab version 10.8.7-ee?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, gitlab-ci-runner

I want to install the GitLab runner version 10.8.7 so that it matches the same version as the GitLab installation that I'm using. I tried to figure out the helm chart version with the following command:

```
helm search repo -l gitlab/gitlab-runner
NAME                    CHART VERSION   APP VERSION DESCRIPTION
gitlab/gitlab-runner    0.15.0          12.9.0      GitLab Runner
...
gitlab/gitlab-runner    0.1.45          11.7.0      GitLab Runner
gitlab/gitlab-runner    0.1.44                      GitLab Runner
gitlab/gitlab-runner    0.1.43                      GitLab Runner
gitlab/gitlab-runner    0.1.42                      GitLab Runner
gitlab/gitlab-runner    0.1.41                      GitLab Runner
...
gitlab/gitlab-runner    0.1.14                      GitLab Runner
gitlab/gitlab-runner    0.1.13                      GitLab Runner
```

but it seems that only chart versions 0.15 to 0.14.5 specify the actual GitLab version (12.9.0 to 11.7.0).

So what chart version corresponds to app version GitLab 10.8.7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed chart version 0.1.34 and that seems to run gitlab runner 11.3.0

```
 cat gitlab-runner-group-values.yml | helm install  --namespace gitlabrunner -f - --version 0.1.34 gitlab-runner-tdh gitlab/gitlab-runner
```

The previous chart version 0.1.33 jumps to gitlab runner 10.3.0

So as far as I know there is no Helm Chart version for [GitLab runner v10.8.0 2018-05-22](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v1080-2018-05-22)

The official [changelog](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/charts/gitlab-runner/-/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) only goes back to version v0.1.45 (2019-01-22) which corresponds to GitLab runner 11.7.0